# MarkerColor with MarkerImage in .NET Charting.Series

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Does anyone know how to use the MarkerColor property when using the MarkerImage property? My chart seems to listen to the MarkerImage and MarkerImageTransparentColor properties but completely ignores MarkerColor and MarkerBorderColor properties. Thanks.

Comment: You should post the code you are using - that will make it easier to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **either** `Markers` **or** `MarkerImages`.

- When using `Markers` you can set the `MarkerColor` and the `MarkerBorderColor`. Also the `MarkerSize`.

**Note** : You also **need** to set the `MarkerStyle`, as it defaults to `None`.

- When using `MarkerImages` you can set one color in the images to be transparent.

As you have found, setting a `MarkerImage` takes **precedence** over the `Markers`.

Also note that you can **mix** `Markers` with `MarkerImages`, if you set them differently for some `Series` and/or `DataPoints`. Here is an example:

[image]

The `Marker` was set for each `Series s`:

```
 s.MarkerColor = Color.OrangeRed;
 s.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
 s.MarkerSize = 5;
```

But for one `DataPoint` in one `Series` I set a `MarkerImage`:

```
 chart.Series[0].Points[3].MarkerImage = "D:\\_png\\rocket.png";
```

Note that I use a disk file here; usually I prefer to add `NamedImages` to the Chart.

Also note that I would have to remove (set to `String.Empty`) the `MarkerImage` from the `DataPoint` when overriding it to display a `Marker`..